# Windows not booting, Asus logo appears and then disappears after 5 seconds

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, asus-laptop

I have an Asus Vivobook X541UA with non-removable battery. I turned it on today after 2 weeks. When I press the power button, the LED indicators light up normally, the OEM logo of Asus appears too but only for a while then the PC turned off on its own. I also tried pressing `esc` and all other function buttons when the logo appears but nothing worked. I also noticed that the fans were not working while charging. I think, there is some problem with the BIOS. How can I fix it by myself at home?

Comment: Does it have Battery remove & reinsert simulation pinhole? Some Acer models have it but I am not sure about Asus. If so, insert a pin and long press for a few seconds to simulate battery removal and reinsertion and retry. Does the battery charging indicator glow when you charge it? Generally issue that you described is indicative of some hardware failure. But this is a very general statement. If it's in warranty, do consider taking it to service center. Is the behavior same when it's on battery and when plugged in?

Comment: If charging appears working, give it a full charge for 2 - 3 hours and retry.

Comment: No, there is nothing like pinhole. Yes it glows and the behaviour is same.